# haskell class property check

Tags: class, haskell, properties

I would like to have a function that checks a property of a class instance:

```
class ListWithAtLeastOneElement a where
   list :: [a]
   check :: Bool
   check = (length list) >= 1
```

but I get this error when compiling in GHC:
"The class method 'check' mentions none of the type variables of the class ListWithAtLeastOneElement a When checking the class method: check :: Bool In the class declaration for 'ListWithAtLeastOneElement'"

Is there a better way of doing what I want, or a way to get this to compile in GHC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think a class in Haskell is like a class in an OO-language. That is not true. You should use a data type or newtype or type synonym.

```
newtype NonemptyList a = List1 [a]

fromList :: [a] -> Maybe (NonemptyList a)
fromList []       = Nothing
fromList xs@(_:_) = Just $ List1 xs

check :: NonemptyList a -> Bool
check (List1 xs) = length xs >= 1
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it would be better to check that a list is `not null` rather than checking the length.  But creating a new datatype as in TomMD's answer would be better still.

Comment: @John: Wether creating a new data type is better depends on the context. If it is a requirement to often convert to and from standard lists, a newtype wrapper is probably better. But I agree that `not null` would be better. I wanted to keep the original posts code in at least one detail.

Answer (score 2):

As jmg said, this isn't valid Haskell so it's good GHC isn't compiling it!  If you're used to Java evidently you should think of Haskell's type classes like Java interface.  If that doesn't help then perhaps you should read [LYAH's chapter on classes](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses).

For you problem, it appears you're wanting a list-like data type that can never be null.  You don't need to *test* for such a property, you can statically ensure it by using a data
type that can never be empty:

```
-- Notice this data type can never have zero 'a' values!
data NonEmptyList a = NEL a (NonEmptyList a) | Singleton a

-- We can define basic operators for this, just like list has
-- You can't pattern match with them, but there are work-arounds for that if you want to ask
(.:) = NEL  -- concatenate non-empty lists

nelHead :: NonEmptyList a -> a 
nelHead (NEL a _) = a
nelHead (Singleton a) = a

nelTail :: NonEmptyList a -> Maybe (NonEmptyList a)
nelTail (NEL _ b) = Just b
nelTail _ = Nothing

nelTake :: Int -> NonEmptyList a -> NonEmptyList a
nelTake 1 (NEL a _) = Singleton a
nelTake 1 (Singleton a) = Singleton a
nelTake n (NEL a rest) = a .: nelTake (n-1) rest

nelDrop :: Int -> NonEmptyList a -> NonEmptyList a
nelDrop _ (Singleton _) = error "Perhaps I should have used the 'maybe' type"
nelDrop 1 (NEL a r) = r
nelDrop n (NEL a r) = nelDrop (n-1) r
```

And so on and so forth.  It's worth noting `nelTake` and `nelDrop` are partial but `nelHead` is total, funny as this is the opposite of regular lists.

Comment: This is generally good practice in functional languages -- instead of saying "it's a list, except ...", devise your data type to have the property *by construction*. Although it can be a bit more boilerplate if you have a lot of operations to support.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make check a function

check :: [a] -> Bool

That said you are better off with a data type for non-empty lists rather than a class, classes in Haskell do not serve the same purpose as classes in object oriented languages.